# pass variables from another dataframe in a case_when statement with dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate, case-when

df1 and df2 are two separated data frame that derived from other logics.

**test data:**

```
df1 <- data.frame(type= c("invite","reminder", "final"))

df2 <- data.frame(delivery_date = date('2018-05-07'))
```

**Question: How can I pass the values of a variable from df2 to df1 (how can I make this code works?)**

```
#pseudocode: 

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

test_d<- df1 %>%
   mutate(send_date = case_when(
          type == "invite" ~ df2$delivery_date
          type == "reminder"  ~ df2$delivery_date + days(2)
          type == "final"  ~  df2$delivery_date + days(4) 
          )
)
```

**data frame I want:**

```
type       send_date
invite    2018-05-07   #pass the value of delivery_date from df1 
reminder  2018-05-09   #add 2 days based on the value of delivery_date in df1
final     2018-05-11   #add 4 days based on the value of delivery_date in df1
```

Comment: You just need commas at the end of each clause of `case_when`

Comment: Good catch! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code as follows. Notice that I used the `data_frame` function to avoid the creation of factor columns. To me, it is easier to work on one data frame, so I used `left_join` to merge the two data frame first. After that, I used the `first` function in the `case_when` call to make sure only one number is used. `df3` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df1 <- data_frame(type= c("invite","reminder", "final"))

df2 <- data_frame(delivery_date = date('2018-05-07'))

df3 <- df1 %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% mutate(type = "invite"), by = "type") %>%
  mutate(delivery_date = case_when(
    type %in% "invite"    ~ first(delivery_date),
    type %in% "reminder"  ~ first(delivery_date) + days(2),
    type %in% "final"     ~ first(delivery_date) + days(4) 
  )) %>%
  rename(send_date = delivery_date)

df3
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   type     send_date 
#   <chr>    <date>    
# 1 invite   2018-05-07
# 2 reminder 2018-05-09
# 3 final    2018-05-11
```